# Grouping and merging of two contacts in XSLT1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>

<CONTACT>
<FirstName>Arun</FirstName>
<LastName>Arun_Neelam</LastName>
<Email>nuraaa_iceee@yahoo.co.in</Email>
</CONTACT>

<CONTACT>
<FirstName>Arun</FirstName>
<LastName>Arun_Neelam</LastName>
<Email>nuraaa_iceee@gmail.com</Email>

</CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

1.How can i merge the above 2 contacts as single contact which is belongs to the same person

I would like to have an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Arun</FirstName>
        <LastName>Arun_Neelam</LastName>
        <Email>nuraaa_iceee@gmail.com</Email>
        <Email>nuraaa_iceee@yahoo.co.in</Email>
</CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

I'm not sure I can do it with `current-group() and current-grouping-key()`. 
Thank you very much for your support.

user639175, he helped for this problem and his solution is working but not giving my desired output. So i have changed the question in a simple way.

Note: I've formatted the question once again completely to avoid confusion in the same thread.

Comment: Just to clarify the question:  Collapse ambigious Names and collect emails ?

Comment: Then may I suggest a solution within the hour - that is I need to reorganise some of your logic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  encoding="windows-1250" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="groupName" match="//CONTACTS/CONTACT" use="concat(FirstName, LastName)" />

<xsl:template match="CONTACTS">

  <CONTACTS>
  <xsl:for-each select="//CONTACTS/CONTACT[generate-id() = generate-id( key('groupName', concat(FirstName, LastName))   [1] ) ]" >
    <xsl:sort select="CONTACT/EMail"  />

      <xsl:call-template name="group">
        <xsl:with-param name="k1" select="FirstName" />
        <xsl:with-param name="k2" select="LastName" />
      </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:for-each>
  </CONTACTS>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="group">
<xsl:param name="k1" /> 
<xsl:param name="k2" /> 

  <CONTACT>
  <xsl:for-each select="//CONTACTS/CONTACT[FirstName = $k1][LastName = $k2][1]">

    <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName" />       
    <xsl:copy-of select="LastName" />       
    <!-- here we have the first Email -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="EMail" />       

  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:for-each select="//CONTACTS/CONTACT[FirstName = $k1][LastName = $k2][position() &gt; 1]">
    <!-- here we have the next Email -->

    <xsl:copy-of select="EMail" />       

  </xsl:for-each>
  </CONTACT>

</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It should work :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a standard grouping technique, you need just two templates (no loops, no params):

- Use a *composite key* to collect **CONTACT** by **FirstName** and **SecondName**.
- Then apply the templates to one single **CONTACT** for each group.
- Finally, retrieve the **Email** nodes from the key.

---

Your final transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="k_Contacts" 
        match="CONTACTS/CONTACT" 
        use="concat(FirstName,LastName)"/>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACTS">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTACT[generate-id()=
                generate-id(key('k_Contacts',concat(FirstName,LastName))[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName | LastName"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('k_Contacts',concat(FirstName,LastName))
              /Email"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In XSLT 2.0 you can use `xsl:for-each-group`; just replace

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="CONTACT[generate-id()=
                generate-id(key('k_Contacts',concat(FirstName,LastName))[1])]"/>
```

with:

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="CONTACT" group-by="concat(FirstName,LastName)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: One question, <CONTACT>
 <FirstName>Arun</FirstName>
<LastName>Neelam</LastName>
<Email>nuraaa_iceee@yahoo.co.in</Email></CONTACT>
<CONTACT><FirstName>Arun</FirstName>
<LastName>Arun_Neelam</LastName>
<Email>nuraaa_iceee@gmail.com</Email></CONTACT>  Here, these two are belongs to the same person but slight difference in the name. How we can merge these two contacts? Thank you.

Comment: That would change the transform in relevant way. Are you still searching for an answer to the question? I've just provided an alternative to the others.

Comment: Could you please explain to me. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971125/merging-different-complex-data-using-xslt-1-0-xml) Did you provide any answer to this question? I couldn't see any answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  encoding="windows-1250" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="groupName" match="//CONTACTS/CONTACT" use="concat(FirstName, LastName)" />

<xsl:template match="CONTACTS">

  <CONTACTS>
  <xsl:for-each select="//CONTACTS/CONTACT[generate-id() = generate-id( key('groupName', concat(FirstName, LastName))   [1] ) ]" >
    <xsl:sort select="CONTACT/EMail"  />

      <xsl:call-template name="group">
        <xsl:with-param name="k1" select="FirstName" />
        <xsl:with-param name="k2" select="LastName" />
      </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:for-each>
  </CONTACTS>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="group">
<xsl:param name="k1" /> 
<xsl:param name="k2" /> 


  <xsl:for-each select="//CONTACTS/CONTACT[FirstName = $k1][LastName = $k2][1]">

    <xsl:copy-of select="." />       

  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did not exclude Arun - because your exmaple has a flaw ? otherwise it works :)

Comment: the 3rd node is not copied - don't you want singletons ?

Comment: <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Arun</FirstName>
        <LastName>Arun_Neelam</LastName>
        <EMail>nuraaa_iceee@yahoo.co.in</EMail>
    </CONTACT> This is the output from your code but it didn't add another email address of the same person. Did you get it?

Comment: singleton equals just one occurence - the solution needs two phases - I gave you the first - you do the second phase - same principles ...

Comment: You meant to group the email values of the same person? I need to do phase2?

Comment: please explain to me a bit more. Thank you