# Merging different complex data using XSLT 1.0 XML

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
    <CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID3</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Arnaaud</FirstName>
    <LastName>Forestier</LastName>
    <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@yahoo.fr</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID5</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Arun_Forestier</FirstName>
    <LastName>Forestier</LastName>
    <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@yahoo.fr</EMail>
    <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@gmail.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID7</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Aana</FirstName>
    <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
    <EMail>Aana.edwards@gmail.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID9</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Aana_Edwards</FirstName>
    <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
    <EMail>Aana.edwards@yahoo.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

     <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID11</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Lina</FirstName>
    <LastName>Joseph</LastName>
    <EMail>Lina.Joseph@aol.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

   <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID13</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>SandfordFrankie</FirstName>
    <LastName>Frankie Sandford/LastName>
    <EMail>Sandford1233@yahoo.com</EMail>
    <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=122112487211054</URL>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID15</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Sandford</FirstName>
    <LastName>Frankie/LastName>
    <EMail>Sandford1233@yahoo.com</EMail>
    <EMail>Sandford.frankie@gmail.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

</CONTACTS>
```

The above XML file has some complex data and this question might look similar  to this question.
[Grouping and merging of two contacts in XSLT1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944514/grouping-and-merging-of-two-contacts-in-xslt1-0)
According to me this data is entirely different(more complex) from the above question, so i'm creating a new question here.

We see the `<Customer-ID>Cus-ID3</Customer-ID> & <Customer-ID>Cus-ID5</Customer-ID>` data belongs to the same person 
because one of his email addess is same. How can I merge these 2 contacts as a single contact?

Another problem, `<Customer-ID>Cus-ID7</Customer-ID> & <Customer-ID>Cus-ID9</Customer-ID>` also belongs to another person. 
Here she has two different emails but in both the contatcs, the

> FirstName & LastName 
>   are same values. How can I merge these 2 contacts as a single contact?

Would it be possible to merge these complex data?

I need an output like this using XSLT-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID5</Customer-ID>
        <FirstName>Arun_Forestier</FirstName>
        <LastName>Forestier</LastName>
        <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@yahoo.fr</EMail>
        <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@gmail.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>


    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>Cus-ID9</Customer-ID>
        <FirstName>Aana_Edwards</FirstName>
        <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
        <EMail>Aana.edwards@yahoo.com</EMail>
    <EMail>Aana.edwards@gmail.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>

</CONTACTS>
```

Please tell me if there is any flaw in my question. Thank you very much.
Note: The email address displayed here are duplicate values.

Comment: There can only be duplicated `CONTACT`nodes or also they can be in group of three or more? That is could we have the situation where a merge between more than 2 nodes is necessary?

Comment: @empo: You are right. Actually there are many duplicate `contact`in my xml file. When i download the user contacts from his/her social networking websites, I found lots of duplicate `contact` in the same name. Here I just showed some part of my xml file!  Thank you very!

Comment: What do you mean with many duplicate. For example could we have a Cus-ID5 to be merged with a Cur-ID9 and, say, with a Cur-ID10 also (triplicates)?

Comment: @empo: Many duplicate in the sense that if a `CONTACT`finds any similarity for example, in my XML file the First 2 `CONTACT`s belongs to the same person 'cause one of his email address reflects same in both the `CONTACT`s. Email address are unique.

Comment: @empo: Any idea to merge these kind of data? Thank you.

Comment: Please show in your xml input all possible complex cases.

Comment: @empo: Please check it out, I have updated my XML file in the question  itself. As i told you already, I have downloaded these contacts from social networking websites. From there, I have found these data. Thank you for your support.

Comment: wow, that's very bad XML and really hard to fix. You should at least have acess to a node-set() function in order to be able to perform multi-pass. Have you this type of function available?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've never heard about this function. That's the reason why I got stuck with this kind of complicated xml file. Please Can you assist Me? Thank you.

Comment: what xslt processor are you using?

Comment: @empo: For testing I use Eclipse JAXB XSl Transformation version 1.0. Originally I execute all my XSL file in XUL Firefox XSLT processor.

Comment: I think FirstName and LastName are too messy. Look at the Sandford duplicate, that's the worst ever; I find difficult to define a rule to merge those two. On which base should I choose the FirstName and secondName of the second node?

Comment: @karthikrangaraj let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2234/discussion-between-empo-and-karthik-rangaraj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here a stylesheet that works as follows:

- merges nodes for which at least an **EMail** is matching
- during merge, **FirstName** and **SecondName** are copied from the first node always
- nodes with no matching **EMail** are copied as is
- nodes without **EMail** nodes are copied as is

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k_ContactsByEmail"
        match="CONTACTS/CONTACT"
        use="EMail"/>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACTS">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTACT[generate-id()=
                generate-id(key('k_ContactsByEmail',EMail)[1])]
                |
                CONTACT[not(EMail)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="
                key('k_ContactsByEmail', EMail)/*
                    [not(.=current()/*)]
                    [not(self::FirstName or self::LastName or self::Customer-ID)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on the XML input provided in the question, it produces:

```
<CONTACTS>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>Cus-ID3</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Arnaaud</FirstName>
      <LastName>Forestier</LastName>
      <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@yahoo.fr</EMail>
      <EMail>Arnaaud_Forestier201111@gmail.com</EMail>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>Cus-ID7</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Aana</FirstName>
      <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
      <EMail>Aana.edwards@gmail.com</EMail>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>Cus-ID9</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Aana_Edwards</FirstName>
      <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
      <EMail>Aana.edwards@yahoo.com</EMail>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>Cus-ID11</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Lina</FirstName>
      <LastName>Joseph</LastName>
      <EMail>Lina.Joseph@aol.com</EMail>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>Cus-ID13</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>SandfordFrankie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Frankie Sandford</LastName>
      <EMail>Sandford1233@yahoo.com</EMail>
      <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=122112487211054</URL>
      <EMail>Sandford.frankie@gmail.com</EMail>
   </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

Comment: it works, thank you. Would you please suggest me the best way to learn XSLT? It seems it's one of the cool technology to deal with XML files and it's really interesting. Thank you once again.

Comment: Use it a lot, follow Stack Overflow questions [xslt] or [xpath] tagged, read @Michael Key or __OReilly__ books, always answer your doubts by reading W3 Recommendation or obviously asking here :)

Comment: Hi, I have a question, in this script if there is no email address in a contact then that particular contact is not copying. For example:    <CONTACT>
    <FirstName>Aana</FirstName>
    <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
    <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=112332323301493096451</URL>
    </CONTACT> if this contact added in the XML file, during the merging process this particular contact is not copying by the script.

Comment: Yes. I want to copy everything if there is no email in the contact.

Comment: You are welcome. Normally, SO answers to complex (but simplified) questions must be considered as a starting point. In this case it was very easy to adapt the solution to the new requirement. Try to invest a bit of time to learn XSLT ;-).

Comment: I have some questions would like to ask?

Comment: I have 4 XSLT files with different functionality. When I execute the file one by one in JS Firefox XSLT processor it works but When I execute simultaneously(called one by one files) it doesn't work. The original xml file is generated from a .part file using java. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Well. I'm sorry but this has nothing to do with the current thread. Please consider of posting a new question with all the details we may need to give you a meaningful answer.